# JPA : Select JPQL with several new

Tags: java, jpa, select, jpql

Could you tell me if it's possible to make a select JPQL with several new Object
like this:

Select new QueryOfSelectionList ( new param(q1, q1t), new param(q2, q2t) ) 
From ...

I success to do like this: new QueryOfSelectionList (q1, q1t, q2, q2t)
but I don't like because I would increase the number of params and have a several constructeur of param possible ( q1, q1t or q1 ).

I tried the example but i have : Exception: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new

this exception is for the new of param(q1,q1t).

thanks for help.

Christian

Answer (score 2):

In the document published at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html, we see that:

Following is the syntax of constructor expression:

> constructor_expression ::= NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {,
>   constructor_item}* )

Further it is said that:

> A constructor may be used in the SELECT list to return one or more
>   Java instances. The specified class is not required to be an entity or
>   to be mapped to the database. The constructor name must be fully
>   qualified.

An example is:

> SELECT NEW com.company.PublisherInfo(pub.id, pub.revenue, mag.price)
>       FROM Publisher pub JOIN pub.magazines mag WHERE mag.price > 5.00

So it is not possible to use the expression like `Select new QueryOfSelectionList ( new param(q1, q1t), new param(q2, q2t) ) From`. Hope this helps.